# Is there an idiom about "dying monkey"?

Tags: idioms, slang, idiom-requests

is there an idiom sounding like "monkey dies" or "monkeys died"? What does it mean?

I've been wondering since I heard Robert Plant song ***"Monkey":***
*Tonight you will be mine |
Tonight the monkey'll die.*

and I also came across it in ***Friends*** when zoo manager said to Ross that *"They say, sometimes monkeys die"* — and the phrase apparently was not used in its literal meaning.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Idioms with monkey: http://fle135-idioms.pbworks.com/w/page/5905557/Idioms-with-Monkey

Comment: It might refer to a serious problem as in : A monkey on someone's back (American & Australian):
a serious problem that will not go away.
The divorce proceedings are a monkey on her back.

Comment: @Josh61 That sounds the most likely in the context of Robert Plant's song. Not an expression I've ever heard before.

Comment: From what I remember of the *Friends* episode, the zoo told Ross that his monkey had died whereas in reality they had sold it to some company (an advertising firm??), ie they lied to hide the fact that they had made money from the sale. The zookeeper was trying to alert Ross to this unscrupulous practice by, in effect, speaking in inverted commas - *They say sometimes monkeys "die".*

Comment: @Josh61-(re: link) Well THAT was educational! Thanks.

Comment: Probably a reference to the idom to have a monkey on one's back - meaning to have a problem that can't be shaken off. I'm assuming he means that making the girl his will relieve his tensions (aka his monkey).

Comment: I think the song (originally by Low, Plant's version is a cover) is deliberately open to being interpreted in a few ways (probably "monkey on my back", perhaps "spanking the monkey" as an interpretation with plausible deniability) while the joke in Friends was the very fact that there is no such saying.

Comment: http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107858520373/ I can't find the date when it was written, perhaps it was 2005. I do know that Friends ended in 2004 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak on the reference to Friends, but the "Robert Plant" song was originally written by Alan Spearhawk and Mimi Parker, and performed by their group "Low". This link includes what Spearhawk had to say about the lyric. Not terribly enlightening, but possibly as close as you'll get to an interpretation.

http://www.ledzeppelinnews.com/2010/09/monkey-band-of-joy-song-of-week-no-11.html?m=1